# How to combine TestMate and Meson?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have two extensions: [Meson](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mesonbuild.mesonbuild) and [C++ TestMate](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=matepek.vscode-catch2-test-adapter). Meson provides a unit test controller which automatically recompiles the unit test. But Meson doesn't actually understand the unit test, it just runs it and it checks if the exit value is 0 or not.

TestMate understands the unit test. But it can't build it.

Is there a way to tie these two down so that the unit test would get automatically recompiled and parsed correctly? I currently have two entries for the same unit test. The unit test shouldn't be executed twice to accomplish this. I know TestMate executes the unit test under the hood, but it only lists the available test.